# Magento 2 : Theme Integration

Tags: theme, magento2.2-dev

I Have one "HTML" theme and want to Integrate into Magento2. I am Already Created Folder structure of the theme. But Don't know how to add header part, footer part in which files. and in which file define theme's "CSS", "JS" etc..

"My Theme Structure"
[image]

I have ".css" files for adding css.

**Output**

[image]

**I Want to Like This:**
[image]

So can anyone help me? I am using Magento version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Templates

You need to overwrite the header and footer templates from the modules (or parent theme if you're using one). You can find these in `magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html`:

```
magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

So you will need to create

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

And add your markup in there, but please note it isn't a case of copying and pasting. You will need to convert your markup into Magento friendly markup, such as using the PHP translations and adding static blocks if it needs to be managed through the admin.

### Static files

To extend your parent theme styling you will need to create this file:

```
app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

And add any of your JS into `app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Theme/web/js` and load it via Require JS.

### Notes

This is the basics to adding your content to a Magento theme, there is too much for me to give a full answer on how to convert your theme. The [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com) are your friend for this.

Comment: For override `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml` simply  create file and put code that's it?

Comment: Yeah, you might need to clear cache as well.

Comment: can you please tell me that `My Account
My Wish List
Sign In
Compare Products  ` where to comes these and how to customize these links

Comment: To find what file renders an element just search for the classes/IDs on the element, there's a good chance this will return a .phtml file. For example the sign in link is in `magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml` so you'll need to copy that file into your theme: `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml`. Or you can use template hints, more info on those can be found here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below tutorials to create theme in magento2. I hope it will also work for you.

http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-on-magento-2-part-1/

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html

These all are good tutorials with detailed description you can follow steps.

Thanks.

Comment: Already Followed All Those Links

Comment: then can you please tell me what exactly problem you are facing ?